# Alternatives to a 3 stack of UISegmentedController iOS

Tags: ios

One view I have is designed in a way that requires 3 separate layers of filtering. The first layer sorts by Image/Video/Person, the second sorts by Day/Week/Month/All Time and the third sorts by Earned/Contributed/Shares.

What are some reasonable alternatives to UI design instead of stacking 3 segmented controllers on top of each other?

Comment: Could you provide a graphic?

Comment: @Mayo Sure - give me a minute. It's literally just 3 segmented controllers stacked on top of one another as described, though.

Comment: sometimes visuals help.

Answer (score 1):

What about this? For iPad you can just use a popover instead of an actionsheet.

[image: mockup]

Answer (score 0):

Is this a search screen? If so, perhaps something like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As I think you're trying to figure out how to merge on one screen two kind of filters: image/video/person and earned/contributed/shares and sorting option by time.

I would try to find inspiration on heavy content loaded apps like apps for hotels and flights searching. You could display two separate button above the list of results, first one would be dedicated to sorting option second one to filtering.

I attach screen from Hipmunk below.

[image: Results] 
[image: Filters]
[image: Sort]